# WebApiContrib Jsonp and Attribute Routing

Tags: jsonp, attributerouting, web-api-contrib, asp.net-web-api2

Per the [WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp GitHub readme](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp), it appears that in the RouteConfig.cs this should be entered:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{format}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, format = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I currently don't have a RouteConfig.cs file in my AppStart. I created it using the Web API 2 template and I don't think I changed anything structurally. I do have a WebApiConfig.cs where I have set:

```
public static void Register (HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

how do I include it such that all routes have the ability to return Jsonp?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom route attribute which implements `IHttpRouteInfoProvider` (which Web API route builder looks for when adding routes to route table) and then modify the template that is being generated by appending `{format}`

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [CustomRoute(Order = 1)]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [CustomRoute("{id}")]
    public string GetSingle(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class CustomRouteAttribute : Attribute, IHttpRouteInfoProvider
{
    public CustomRouteAttribute()
    {
        Template = String.Empty;
    }

    public CustomRouteAttribute(string template)
    {
        if (template == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("template");
        }

        if (template == string.Empty)
        {
            Template = template + "{format?}";
        }
        else
        {
            Template = template.TrimEnd('/') + "/{format?}";
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public string Template { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this now. Could you explain this a bit more? Does the jQuery client do anything other than request jsonp? Not sure where the {format} part comes into play.

Comment: I don't know how JsonP actually works :-)...probably webapicontrib is the place to find more about this...i just wanted to show how you can enable modifying the template...

Comment: I would suggest to open a different question regarding understading jsonp and webapicontrib implementatoin.

Comment: I had previously posted about this to the issues section of the Github site for the project (https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp/issues/19), was just trying here unless someone else has run into it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this comment in a [pull request](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp/pull/21/files) but I don't understand if this is yet implemented into the production package nor if it got pulled at all.

> If you are using Attribute Routing, you should add "/{format}" after each route if you plan to use the URI mapping for jsonp, e.g. `[Route("api/value/{id:int}/{format?}")]`. If you will require the `Content-Type` header to specify `text/javascript`, then you can leave your routes alone. (See the sample applications for examples.)